# Uncaught Exception Saving String NSUserDefaults [Swift]

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults, uncaught-exception

I am trying to save an inputted string from a text field and load that saved value using NSUserDefaults. When I run my code, the app crashes when I hit the "saveScore" button. My error message is "terminating with uncaught exception," but I can't find what's actually wrong.

```
class ScoreViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var loadDataButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var mathScore: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var testMath: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveScore: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var displayDataLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func saveDataClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        saveData()
    }


    func saveData() {

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        let latestScore = mathScore.text

        defaults.setObject(latestScore, forKey: "12/1")

        defaults.synchronize()

    }


    @IBAction func loadDataClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        if let firstNameIsNotNill = defaults.objectForKey("12/1") as? String {
            self.displayDataLabel.text = defaults.objectForKey("12/1") as String
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems the problem is not with NSUserDefault, i run your code.

Comment: What should I try to solve my problem?

Comment: Why you took all weak IBOutlets? Make them Strong and try.

Comment: Are you sure that's all there is in your error message?  Usually there will be some detail about the reason for the exception.

Comment: One of more of your `IBOutlet` might be referencing something that doesn't exist anymore. Maybe try checking your storyboard.

Comment: A note: you're doing `if let firstNameIsNotNill = ...` but then you're not using `firstNameIsNotNill` inside for assigning to the label, you're using the one that may be nil.

Comment: @EricD. It should work i tried, also you are correct.

Comment: I checked my connections, and it turns out that my connection for saveScore and loadDataButton are bad. I deleted and re-created the connections, but the connections continue to be bad. Any thoughts?

Comment: Exactly the problem is there, how you are creating connections? Remove the weak reference.

Comment: I fixed my problem by restarting xCode -- the connections wouldnt save until i rebooted the program. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Restarting XCode fixed the problem!